# My chrome can not sync and even edge and also chromium web browser can not save password too

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, microsoft-edge, opera

I don't know what happened to my PC - all the chromium web browsers like Edge, Chrome, Opera can't save passwords. Even when I manually add password, it cannot save. My saved password session on Chrome go to blank after I click "Add password" manually in Chrome.

If I log in to Chrome, it cannot sync. Also, when I close Chrome, and re-open it, the sync status stays paused, and it makes me log in again. Also, password sync doesn't sync passwords in "saved password" section.

I try Opera, Edge - it is the same problem as chrome. Only Firefox can sync and saved password and auto-fill functions work!

What I'd tried:

- clear cookie data on Chrome
- even go to Local folder of Chrome of my PC to delete manually
- check setting (save password, add web always use cookie etc.)
- even re-install Chrome doesn't help.
- Delete the files "Login Data" and "Login Data-journal".

I tried all the way over the Internet about Chrome setting but nothing helps.

I use Windows 8.1 pro and Free Avast Antivirus on my PC.
Re-installing or upgrading Windows is not an option because I have too many installed applications - installing them all over again is not practical for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Recently I was having the exact same problem with all browsers (didn't try firefox tho) on my work PC. After windows update it was fixed, only to come back a few days later. But this time it fixed itself, after I installed a number of browsers (vivaldi, opera, brave).

Answer (score 0):

If a browser needs to be reset at this level, you should probably simply uninstall the browser and reinstall it.

If you cannot do this, you could go to `C:\Users\(username)\AppData\` then open the LocalLow and Roaming folders and find the folders for the browsers you are hoping to fix and delete only their contents.

Do not delete the entire contents of the Roaming or LocalLow folders. Doing so will damage other applications on your computer.

Always run backups before deleting things.

Comment: that advice is better. But i dont know exactly which folder need to be delete in LocalLow and Roaming Folder.

Comment: They're usually named for the application they belong to.

Comment: This doesn't help, and cannot help, cause the OP has already said they tried uninstalling and reinstalling the browser itself, which does indeed delete the user profile data you mentioned. And if it is a browser specific issue, it would be limited to that browser only, but the OP said they were having the same issue on multiple browsers.